# glyphicon without using library

Tags: css

Is it possible to load a bootstrap icon without loading the entire library? I tried pasting the bootstrap fonts into the css, but still no luck- can this be accomplished?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('/fonts/ChaparralPro-Regular.woff');
  src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('/font/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf');
  src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff');
  src: url('/font/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2');
  src: url('/fonts/kievitot-book-webfont.woff');
 src: url('fonts/Segoe_ui-webfont.woff');
}

.glyphicon-thumbs-up:before {
  content: "\e125";
}
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
 <i class="glyph-icon icon-chevron-down"></i>
```

Comment: You can get a download of glyphicon halflings for free from http://glyphicons.com/ and just pull out the png if you want instead of loading the whole webfont

Comment: In the past I've used: [fontastic.me](http://fontastic.me/) which allows one to combine multiple glyphicons into one sheet for use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [flaticon.com](http://flaticon.com) you can search through a lot of icons and it auto generates a stylesheet and a font file, with multiple extensions. So you can easily import to your project.